# Is there a shortcut to insert a basic html editor page in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I have recently installed visual studio code and started some projects on it. The thing is when I was using sublime text I didn't need to type out the Doctype HTML html etc.. attributes when I needed a new html page. I just had to type html and press the tab key and the basic editor page would be inserted for me. So my question is, is there a way to do this in Visual Studio Code ?

Comment: use Emmet snippet `!` or write your own snippet like  I have.

Answer (score 1):

You can install emmet extension from the vs code marketplace inside of vs code interface and it works perfectly the same as you used to do in sublime.

Comment: The emmet functionality is built-in, no need for an extension.